# mirror STDOUT and STDERR to file by default

Tags: bash, redirection, zsh, stream

How I can accomplish STDOUT to be to logged in a file (appending), but preserving the flow (leave STDOUT to STDOUT) ?

STDOUT should work transparently, but should be logged also into a file, without messing with "tee" on each command input. Same for STDERR.

Simply, mirror output to file.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of: `script`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the 'script' command...

```
script -a
(run your commands)
exit
```

This will create a file called typescript that records all commands that you input and their respective output.

Comment: nice. I never knew that this existed!